# How to check whether it is dns issue, browser issue or server setting issue?

Tags: django, nginx, dns

I have deployed [www.stochie.com](http://www.stochie.com) successfully

point is now I want to create a subdomain for 'idx.stochie.com' and point it to a new server with IP address 54.179.144.127.

I check the DNS already link 'idx.stochie.com' to IP address 54.179.144.127. (https://dnschecker.org/#A/idx.stochie.com)
It is ok if I try to go to 54.179.144.127 via my browser but when I tried to go to the address, I get "Hmmm… can't reach this page idx.stochie.com took too long to respond"

I am using nginx and here is the config:

```
server {
server_name idx.stochie.com
            ''
            54.179.144.127;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static {
    root /home/ubuntu/stochie/;
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
if ($host = 'stochie.com') {
    return 301 https://www.stochie.com$request_uri;
}
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/idx.stochie.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/idx.stochie.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}




server {
if ($host = idx.stochie.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbotlisten 80;

server_name idx.stochie.com
            ''
            54.179.144.127;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

for the webserver, I am using Django and I have add "idx.stochie.com" to the ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py

For the starter I am not sure whether my browser managed to get the IP address from the DNS providers. Any idea where I can start looking at?

Comment: You are missing quotes in `if ($host = idx.stochie.com)`

Comment: I changed to if ($host = "idx.stochie.com") but still not working. same error